# Given a language, define its CFG

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

Given

```
L1 = {w belongs to {a,b}* | has as many a as b}
```

Define a CFG G such that L(G)= L1

In my opinion these productions should be the right answer

```
1) S → aSa

2) S → bSb

3) S → ε
```

My reasoning  was:

L1 contains strings like { ab,aabb,aaabbb,...etc}

Now I have a doubt: if I apply the above productions , in a nutshell:

`S → aSa`
I apply the 1) so I get `S → aSa → aaSaa` the I choose 2) an I get `S → aSa → aaSaa → aabSbaa` and then using the empty string I get the final string  `S → aSa → aaSaa → aabSbaa → aabbaa`

Now, maybe I'm wrong but in the string `aabbaa`the number of a is not equal to the number of b

Any help will be highly appreciated

Joachim

Comment: Anyway, consider this input which is *not matched*: "abab". Therefore, the posted productions *can't* be the right answer. Happy theoreticalstuffitizing.

Comment: If you think that my post should be tagged as homework..I do hope someone can explain to me where I make mistakes and why..

Comment: After every production, the number of `a`s and `b`s should be equal. You current solution depends on choosing the right productions but as you already noticed, this cannot be guaranteed. You have to make sure that every production generates a valid word.

Comment: consider this input which is not matched: "abab"...So how should I solve the problem?

Comment: But if I start applying the 2) rule I get abSba then through the 3) I get abba where a and b are equal in number..Am I right?

Comment: the solution is : S--> aSbS|bSaS|eps.....right?

Comment: now find an unambiguous grammar for this language : )

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard class exercise, which does not yet have a correct answer.

```
1) S -> aSb
2) S -> bSa
3) S -> SS
4) S -> ε
```

Any number of a's and b's in any order, including the empty string.

---

There are quite a few online class notes with the answers and proofs. Examples:
[here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/lectures/disc_07.pdf), [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ib/Classes/CS380_Fall09/Slides/061-ContextFreeGrammars.pdf), [here](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ko/pdfs/lecture-7.pdf), and [here](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/Classes/Archives/cse460.03spring/Lectures/Module30.pdf) to show a few.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the L1 is in fact `{a^nb^n | n ≥ 0}`, the grammar you provided cannot (as you proved yourself) produce exactly L1. To satisfy the requirement that, loosely expressed, "the number of `a`'s on the left side of a word must be equal to the number of `b`'s on its right side", your objective is to find a grammar that enforces that requirement after each and every one of its productions.

Another way to think about this is: you are not allowed to use productions in your grammar that do not generate an equal number of `a` and `b`.

edit: Since this isn't homework, I'll go ahead and give the answer:

```
V = {A}, Σ = {a, b}, S = A, and R the set of rules:

(1) A -> aAbA | bAaA
(2) A -> ε
```

Comment: What about abab? Your grammar produces some strings with same number of a's and b's but not all.

Comment: I still think you don't get all possible words with your solution. E.g. As I understand a word can start with a and also end with a (e.g. abba) which is not possible with your rules.

Comment: @Howard aAbA => aAbbAaA =>* abba

Answer (score -1):

Sorry maybe I'm wrong but Michael Foukarakis'solution doesn't work

Basically these two rules do not provide strings having the same number of a and b.

```
(1) A -> aAb

(2) A -> ε
```

Take A -> aAb and then apply the 1) rule, you have `A -> aAb ->aaAb` and then???
If you apply the 2) you end up getting `A -> aAb ->aaAb ->aab`

I think the right answer is:

```
1)S->aSbS

2)S->bSaS

3) S->ε
```

Even though I get strings like : `abab` or `aababb`
Actually they both fulfill the initial requirements , which is :

```
the string must contain the same number of a and b.
```

(it doesn't matter how the elements are arranged..)

Comments, of course are welcome and encouraged.

Comment: You say `A -> aAb -> aaAb` - how that? Is there a rule which replaces `A` by `a`?